# Rethrowing exceptions in nested promise chains

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to figure out a clean way to chain promises in AngularJs. My goal is to not rewrap the $http promise using $q and to instead take advantage of the fact that $http.xxx() methods return promises and use chaining. In the below code I'm trying to satisfy the following Use Case.

Note: If I remove the innner .catch() block my 404 will get caught by the outer catch(). I've tried using the then(actionHandler, errorHandler) approach as well as tried returning a string from .catch() and tried using this.reject() in .catch().

```
Give $scope.username is Bret 
When calling getPosts() and getting a 404 from /users 
Then scope.error has a message indicating that the user wasn't found
```

// Code

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, $log, $q, $http) {
        $scope.posts = [];
        $scope.message = "";

        function getUserByUserName(userName) {

            return getUsers()
                .then(function (response) {

                    var user;

                    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                        if (response.data[i].username === userName) {
                            user = response.data[i];
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    return user;
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    throw "User could not be found.";
                });
        };

        function getUsers() {
            return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
        }

        function getPostByUser(user){

            return getPosts()
                .then(function (posts) {

                    var postsByUser = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                        if (posts[i].userId === user.id) {
                            postsByUser.push(posts[i]);
                        }
                    }

                    return postsByUser;
                });
        }

        function getPosts() {
            return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        };

        function addPostsToScope(posts) {

            $log.debug('MainController.getPostByUserName reponse.length: ' + posts.length);

            $scope.posts.length = 0;

            $scope.posts.username = $scope.username;

            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                $scope.posts.push(posts[i]);
            }
        };

        $scope.getPosts = function () {
            getUserByUserName($scope.username)
                .then(getPostByUser)
                .then(addPostsToScope)
                .catch(function (error) {
                        $scope.error = error;
                });
        };
    });
```

// Tests

```
describe('MainController', function () {

var endpointController;

var dummyPosts = [
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
        "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "qui est esse",
        "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
    },
    {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 11,
        "title": "et ea vero quia laudantium autem",
        "body": "delectus reiciendis molestiae occaecati non minima eveniet qui voluptatibus\naccusamus in eum beatae sit\nvel qui neque voluptates ut commodi qui incidunt\nut animi commodi"
    }];

var dummyUsers = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "address": {
            "street": "Kulas Light",
            "suite": "Apt. 556",
            "city": "Gwenborough",
            "zipcode": "92998-3874",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-37.3159",
                "lng": "81.1496"
            }
        },
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
        "company": {
            "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
            "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
            "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Ervin Howell",
        "username": "Antonette",
        "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
        "address": {
            "street": "Victor Plains",
            "suite": "Suite 879",
            "city": "Wisokyburgh",
            "zipcode": "90566-7771",
            "geo": {
                "lat": "-43.9509",
                "lng": "-34.4618"
            }
        },
        "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
        "website": "anastasia.net",
        "company": {
            "name": "Deckow-Crist",
            "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
            "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
        }
    }];

beforeEach(module('app'));

it('Give $scope.username is Bret When calling getPosts() and getting a 404 from /users Then scope.error has a message indicating that the user wasnt found',
    inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {

        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .respond(404, null, null, "Not Found");
        $httpBackend.whenGET('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .respond(dummyPosts);

        var scope = $rootScope.$new();

        scope.username = 'Bret';

        endpointController = $controller("MainController", { $scope: scope });

        scope.getPosts();

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(endpointController).toBeTruthy();
        expect(scope.error).toBeTruthy();
        expect(scope.error).toBe("User could not be found.");
    }));
```

});

**EDIT**
I've added a plunker here that shows the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/URMFfeM9IHPUGDbydZfa?p=preview

The expected console output is

```
That user could not be found.
outer catch block reached!
```

but it's writing out

```
That user could not be found.
getPosts
getPosts.Then()
getPostsByUser()
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, to clarify the question is how to do I make the inner catch propagate to the outer catch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `return $q.reject(error)` inside the catch:

```
return getUsers()
    .then(function (response) {
        var user;

        for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            if (response.data[i].username === userName) {
                user = response.data[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return user;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return $q.reject(error);
    });
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qFRv7kltodhcdy1OD85o?p=preview) with a small demo demonstrating catching the exception and re-throwing it.

Comment: That clearly demonstrates what I'm trying to do but for some reason I can't make it work in my code. I've updated your Plunkr above with a trimmed down demo of my code path which is not working. It seems so similar to yours but I can't seem to spot the difference that's causing it to break. Do you see anything causing the issue there?